# Remove illegal markup from xml string (node starting with number)

Tags: java, xml, regex, json

I am converting a JSON Array to a XML string:

`JSONArray json = new JSONArray(response);
xml = XML.toString(json);`

and unfortunately the result contains nodes like 
`<24x24>blah</24x24>`

Afterwards I want to create a 'real' XML Node with SAXBuilder which produces following error:

`The content beginning "<2" is not legal markup. Perhaps the "2" (&#32;) character should be a letter.`

Does anybody know how to remove this illegal markup from the XML String?
Maybe a regex which replaces `<24x24>blah</24x24>` with `<t24x24>blah</t24x24>`?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using `String.replaceAll()` method with regex. [Live demo](http://regex101.com/r/nT9pP8/2)

```
System.out.println("<24x24>blah</24x24>".replaceAll("(<\\/?)(?=\\d)", "$1t"));
```

output:

```
<t24x24>blah</t24x24>
```